# TestNG try/catch not working properly

Tags: java, selenium, try-catch, testng

I am working on a test automation framework that someone previously built. The framework reads test data from an excel file and uses Selenium webdriver to control the browser and perform tests.

I am adding functionality to this framework by adding a TestNG class that reads data from a CSV file. Some functions in the current framework use try/catch. So when I call these functions from the TestNG class, TestNG will always say that the test passed, no matter what.

For example, this is from the current framework;

```
    if (enterValueInBox.length() >= 1) {
        try {
            browserActions.typeValueInTextBox(myDriver, enterValueInBox);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("enterValueInBox failed");
        }
    }
```

This if statement is inside a function. It doesn't matter whether this functions works or not, it will always pass in TestNG. Even if Selenium can not find the element for example.

How can I work around this? Do I have to change the try/catch?

EDIT: Another example from the same function. The function basically consists of several if statements just like the two I am showing here. They all have the same signature, so an if statement with try/catch inside. Also worth mentioning, the function/class I am calling is not a TestNG class. So I built a TestNG class, and calling a non-TestNG class->method.

```
   if (backSpaceInTextBox.length() > 1) {
        try {
            wa.handleSeleneseCommand(myDriver, Properties.TIME_TO_WAIT,
                    "niet gelukt");
            browserActions.doBackSpaceInTextBox(myDriver,
                    backSpaceInTextBox);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not do backspace");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add more code from your test ?

Comment: Your catch clause is actually just swallowing the exception. It prints a message to the console and continues normal execution. You need to handle the exception in some way, or else declare in your method signature that an error is thrown

Comment: @ToYonos
I am trying to be carefull with the code because it's internal. But what kind of code do you want to see? See the edit above ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tests are passing because test function completes

- without any assertion failures
- without exception thrown from test method

In your case, you should do one of

- do not catch exceptions at all. Declare test methods to throw those exceptions
- catch exception and fail test (`Assert.fail`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
if (enterValueInBox.length() >= 1)
{
    try
    {
        browserActions.typeValueInTextBox(myDriver, enterValueInBox);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Assert.fail("EnterValueInBox failed", e);
    }
}
```

Your test will fail when an Exception is thrown.